# Word processor Application for apple Ipad - need suggestions

Tags: iphone, ios4, ipad, itunes, word-processor

I am thinking of creating an word processor application for Ipad which can have basic function like opening, editing and saving.

I need suggestion from you all, about this. (Related application, any third party libraries/sources I can use this for).

Any help is appreciated.

Thank You!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to get to know [Core Text](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/CoreText_Programming/Introduction/Introduction.html). You'll need to handle all the text rendering yourself (including things like drawing the magnifying glass when the user is selecting stuff), as that's the only way you can get styleable editable text. (Well, you can also do it with a webview and contentEditable, but that's not recommended for writing a word processor.)